# memcached doesn't start on vagrant up with CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, vagrant, centos6.5

I'm trying to provision a development box with Vagrant and a CentOS 6.5 base box. I want memcached to automatically start at system boot/vagrant up.

I have tried adding `memcached -d -l localhost -p11211` to /etc/rc.d/rc.local and this does not work.

I have also tried adding to /etc/init/vagrant-mounted.conf

```
start on vagrant-mounted
memcached -d -l localhost -p11211
```

[EDIT]

I've updated `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` to now use the following

```
chkconfig memcached on
service memcached start
```

I'm not seeing anything in the /var/log/boot.log.  It looks like rc.local is not being run at all.  It has ugo+x permissions; so the file is definitely executable, but it doesn't appear to run at all.

Comment: Similar questions and more info here: http://serverfault.com/questions/201981/launch-memcached-on-server-boot

Answer (score 0):

Does memcached -d -l localhost -p11211 exit immediately or spawn a process?

If it keeps running, try: nohup memcached -d -l localhost -p11211 &

Also, try putting it in /etc/rc.local as
memcached -d -l localhost -p11211 >/var/log/memcached.log 2>&1

That will give you a log file with possible errors.
Lastly, does your install of memcached not have an init.d file in /etc/init.d ?
if it does, simply do chkconfig servicename on && service servicename start

Comment: From the terminal it starts up find as a process and runs in the background without needing `&` at the end.  Neither of these settings in the rc.local started either.  Sending output to /var/log/memcached.log isn't even creating a log file.  I checked permissions and rc.local is executable.  If I run it after being logged in it starts fine, but it doesn't start a boot.